# In terms of databases, what does 'roach motel' mean?

Tags: database-design

Recently Larry used it in one of the [OpenWorld keynotes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=XLmtD3CanpM#t=1257s).

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roach_motel) says

> In computers, sometimes as slang use:
>
> - Sometimes used to refer to a proprietary file standard -- "you can check your data in, but you can't check it out".

I fail to understand the meaning here. In what situations will one not be able to check out the data?

Comment: SFW http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4c2gadmytg

Answer (score 5):

Generally, I understand (could be wrong of course) it to be either

- opaque vendor lock-in
- difficulty in re-using data how you want

The second point is seen every day

You buy an app that runs on a mainstream RDBMS: you can report on data, extract it, mine it whatever. Or you buy an app that locks the data into some internal, opaque, proprietary format (not a well known one like PDF or DOC or XLS) where you are forced to use the vendor's (perhaps limited) API.

A couple of other examples

- [Larry Ellison on Salesforce](http://techcrunch.com/2011/10/06/ellison-reveals-oracles-public-cloud-calls-salesforce-the-roach-motel-of-cloud-services/)
- [Facebook vs Twitter](http://scobleizer.com/2009/04/27/facebook-still-a-data-roach-motel-when-compared-to-twitter-and-friendfeed/)